# Unable to get HTML source code Selenium , Python of Zomato website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Zomato website for reviews, but I am unable to get the source HTML code from the website. I am trying to get the Review box, but it returns null or "NoneType".
here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import nltk
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from tensorflow import keras
os.system('cls')


PATH = "C:\\Users\\HCES\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
i=1
html = driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/beirut/divvy-ashrafieh/reviews?page= 
{}&sort=dd&filter=reviews-dd".format(i))
driver.quit()
#soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
#tag=soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'sc-esoVGF cHxNXn')
#print(atag)
print(html)
```

Comment: Have you tried waiting for it to load, using a webdriver wait? There is a possibility that those elements are added dynmically, so its better to do a wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

you are trying to return from `driver.get()` but instead it should be

```
driver.page_source
```

See below :

```
i=1
driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/beirut/divvy-ashrafieh/reviews?page= {}&sort=dd&filter=reviews-dd".format(i))
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,"lxml")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is my first time web scraping so excuse the dumb mistakes.